# Wrapping children of an element with nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nokogiri

I have a document structured like this:

```
<root> 
   <element>1</element>
   <element>2</element>
   <element>3</element>
</root>
```

And i would like to wrap elements in another tag to end up with:

```
<root>
  <container> 
   <element>1</element>
   <element>2</element>
   <element>3</element>
  <container>
</root>
```

I know I can get all the elements, delete them, create a new node, put elements inside it, and add the new node as a child to root. Was wondering if Nokogiri has a helper method for smth like that.

Thank you.